# Reduced UriTemplate dosnt works

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have Asp.Net Web Api project.

With nexts key code parts:

1.

> routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =
>   UrlParameter.Optional } );

1. > RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("files", new
   >   WebServiceHostFactory(),  typeof(UploadManager)));
2. UploadManager contains method

> [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}/{description}", Method
>   = "POST")] public void UploadFile(string fileName, string description, Stream fileContents)

1. Client uses HttpWebRequest with requestUrlString "files/UploadFile/somefile.txt/somedesc"

It works. =)

But I need to remove description parameter. Simply removing one from UriTemplate, method UploadFile and on client requestUrlString causes after call GetResponse 404. Why?
Do I need change routes?

I tried with next client urls
 a) "files/UploadFile/somefile.txt"
 b) "files/UploadFile/somefiletxt"
 c) "files/UploadFile/somefile.txt/" (and last slash on server side too).

Comment: Solved! At first you should add ServiceRoute and then next call routes.MapRoute =)